# Game physics simulation: accelerate based on energy

Tags: javascript, game-physics

Countless times I've implemented physics simulations using Euler integration for little toy games: press arrow key and it sets an acceleration, then integrate acceleration and add to velocity, then integrate velocity and add to position to get final position. I see this everywhere.

But when I thought about kinetic energy, I realized it's not "realistic". If given something like a car, the engine produces power (kW), not force/acceleration. With constant acceleration, the virtual engine's power increases as velocity increases. In my case it's a spaceship but I want to experiment with applying constant power in a direction instead of constant acceleration.

Is my assessment correct that tracking energy is more realistic than acceleration? If so, does it actually make more sense to keep track of energy vector instead of velocity vector? But then I have to convert to velocity to integrate. So I've done this for 1D simulation and it works, of course I can use E=0.5*m*v*v and solve for v. But what about when using vectors, where I can't take the "square root" of energy (vector). I could find the vector whose direction is the same but the magnitude is the square root of the original, but is that physically correct?

I thought surely someone must be doing this, but I've searched and searched the web and don't see it. So maybe I'm off base.

Essentially, what I want to do is take the traditional "push up arrow and spaceship accelerates at a constant acceleration" and change it into "push up arrow and spaceship gains kinetic energy at a constant rate" but handle this in a 2D case instead of a 1D case (I have 1D case working already).

Update: JavaScript code based on Exceptyon's accepted answer:

```
function sq(x) {
    return x * x;
}

//Square cosine, preserving sign
function cos2(x) {
    var ret = Math.cos(x);
    if (ret >= 0) {
        return sq(ret);
    } else {
        return -sq(ret);
    }
}

//Square sine, preserving sign
function sin2(x) {
    var ret = Math.sin(x);
    if (ret >= 0) {
        return sq(ret);
    } else {
        return -sq(ret);
    }
}

function Ship() {
    this.x = 20; //m
    this.y = 40; //m
    this.dx = 0; //m/s
    this.dy = 0; //m/s
    this.ex = 0; //J
    this.ey = 0; //J
    this.pangle = Math.PI / 2; //pointing angle

    this.mass = 1; //kg
    this.power = 200; //W

    this.update = function(dt) {/*...*/} //update x/y based on dx/dy

    /**
     * Direct translation of Exceptyon's equations, but preserving sign in cos^2, sin^2 and sqrt
     * operations.
     * @param dt delta time in seconds
     */
    this.speedup2 = function(dt) {
        this.ex += this.power * dt * cos2(this.pangle);
        this.ey += this.power * dt * -sin2(this.pangle);
        var signx = this.ex > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        var signy = this.ey > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        this.dx = Math.sqrt(2 * Math.abs(this.ex) / this.mass) * signx;
        this.dy = Math.sqrt(2 * Math.abs(this.ey) / this.mass) * signy;
    };

    /**
     * Modified variation of Exception's post where I transform energy "vector" into velocity, that
     * I believe is equivalent.
     */
    this.speedup = function(dt) {
        this.ex += Math.cos(this.pangle) * this.power * dt;
        this.ey += -Math.sin(this.pangle) * this.power * dt;
        var totalEnergy = Math.sqrt(this.ex * this.ex + this.ey * this.ey);
        var speed = Math.sqrt(2 * totalEnergy / this.mass);

        var ratio = speed / totalEnergy;
        this.dx = this.ex * ratio;
        this.dy = this.ey * ratio;

        this.speed = Math.sqrt(this.dx * this.dx + this.dy * this.dy);
    };
}
```

Comment: Energy is a scalar quantity. You need to be handling vector quantities like force and acceleration. You had it right before. BTW - energy increases as the square of velocity. Constant acceleration gives exponentially increasing energy.

Comment: I think you might be confusing some basic physics concepts. "Constant energy" doesn't make sense for acceleration; for example a full tank of fuel has constant energy, it's just sitting there. Power is the rate at which that energy is applied. The first hit on Google for this is http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/work.html which might help.

Comment: there is no direction for energy. Also there is no such thing as which is more "realistic" as they are both real and they are basically looking at the same thing but with a different angle. In your case, the more "suitible" one is the vector approach, which is a/v/s (also, this post has nothing to do with programming)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about physics, not programming

Comment: @GregHewgill, sorry I meant constant power (edited my post). Instead of applying for example 2m/s^2 each frame, I want to apply 200kW for example. For example if we think of a trivial car examples, cars are rated in power (HP or kW), not in m/s^2. Therefore, your velocity over time is not a straight line but curved.

Comment: @MikeW, it is about programming, I'm doing a JavaScript game at the moment. I almost put this in physics exchange but questions there are about quantum mechanics and dark matter, while in StackExchange I found lots of game-physics tagged items closer to what I'm asking. so my question is given the standard acceleration/velocity/position vector game loop, how can I modify it so that constant power instead of constant acceleration is applied...

Comment: If you want to focus on making a good game and not on reinventing the wheel I would suggest finding a good physics framework to solve these issues for you. I make my games in C# and love Farseer. http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/

Comment: @JensB, normally I'd agree 1000% but this project isn't actually a real game it's specifically just a learning task for building a simple thing in JavaScript and also I'm specifically interested in learning the physics here. The "final" product is just going to be a spaceship that can turn and fly around in browser. For a real game, I would use a library most definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that if you want, you just have to keep track of kinetic energy along x and y (and z if you are moving in 3d).

```
Ex = kinetic energy along x-axis
Ey = kinetic energy along Y-axis
//Etot = Ex + Ey
//dt = 1/fps
```

ofc if you don't like cartesian `Ex, Ey` you could keep `Etot, direction`, it's completely equivalent. conversion would be:

```
Ex = Etot * cos^2(direction)
Ey = Etot * sin^2(direction)
```

and inverse:

```
Etot = Ex + Ey
direction = atan2(sqrt(Ey), sqrt(Ex))
```

at a given frame your engine would give you Power*dt energy, that is

```
\delta{Ex} = Power*dt * cos^2(direction)
\delta{Ey} = Power*dt * sin^2(direction)
```

and from there, you should find that every frame:

```
//Etot = E_x + E_y
//vtot = sqrt(2*Etot/m)
v_x = sqrt(2*Ex/m) // = vtot*cos(direction)
v_y = sqrt(2*Ey/m) // = vtot*sin(direction)
```

Comment: Since I had 1D case working, my first approach was to try x and y separately as you did, but it didn't work as maybe I missed a step? 1D case: Let's say dt=1 second and mass 1kg, power 2kW. First frame starting from a stop, 2 kW * 1s = 2J. sqrt(2*2J/1kg) = 2 m/s. Next frame, now energy is 4J and velocity 2.83 m/s. So now we try 2D case at 30 degree angle, so power_x = cos(30deg)*2kW=1.73kW and power_y = 1kW. After 2 seconds, Ex=3.46J, Ey=2J. Etot then is 4J, as expected. vx=sqrt(2*3.46J/1kg)=2.63m/s, vy=2m/s, vtot=3.30, which is not the expected 2.83m/s.

Comment: I think the vx_1 calculation is not right because you have to treat energy and velocity as scalars. I found two equivalent ways that work: one is treat energy as a vector then when converting to velocity, velocity = energy_vector / Etot * vtot. Other way is to compute velocity before and after then apply the change of velocity in the direction of the thrust (I don't know if that simplifies to your equation to calculate a, if Ex was replaced with Etot). I chose the energy vector method because I think it is more accurate under Euler integration.

Comment: I've edited, i made a mistake, it's Etot=Ex+Ey since v^2 = vx^2 + vy^2

Comment: The edited version works, although I have to preserve sign through the cos^2,sin^2, and sqrt calculations when angles are more than pi/2. The whole Etot=Ex+Ey is strange, but works, I guess it's no longer a typical vector as normal vector magnitude doesn't apply. My "v = e * vtot / Etot" method I believe is exactly equivalent and appears the same when I run the "game", but required a lot less code and the same number of complex calculations (1 cos, 1sin, 2 sqrt). I'll paste the final code into my question soon.